# Python - Tkinter correct way to setup an exit button on a child window and how it affects a toggle button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi, exit, togglebutton

I'm a newbie trying to learn Python with the Raspberry Pi.  I've been writing some code to try to make a simple emulator for the piFace add on board.

There are a few issues with it and I'm learning as I work my way through them.

The code opens a main window and shows eight toggle buttons which each toggle an LED on/off.  I also added a button that opens a child window.
The child window has two buttons.  One is a on/off toggle button that makes the 8 LED's stream back and forth like Knight Rider, the other is an Exit button.

My problem is that when the LED's are streaming back and forth if I use the Exit button the child window closes, as it should.  But if I re-open the child window and use the toggle button to turn the streaming LED's on, nothing happens.  If I press the toggle button again the LED's start to stream as normal.

I kind of understand what the problem is.  Because I close the window when the LED's are streaming the toggle button state is still in the ON state.  And, when I re-open the window and click the toggle button I'm just setting the toggle button state to OFF.

I'm not sure how to address the problem.  Should I look at closing the window a different and probably correct way?  Should I look at a way of presetting the state of the toggle switch?  Should I try something completely different?  Should I stop altogether?  :-)

I hope that makes some sense.

Thanks for any help.

Here's my code....

```
# Idle 10_01_2014_GUI label image toggle
from time import sleep
import piface.pfio as pfio
pfio.init()

from Tkinter import *

import Tkinter as tk
import threading

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
            self.master=master
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=0, column=1)

            self.button0 = Button(frame, text='LED 0 OFF', command=self.convert0)
            self.button0.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.LED0 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=1)

            self.button1 = Button(frame, text='LED 1 OFF', command=self.convert1)
            self.button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
            self.LED1 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED1.grid(row=3, column=1)

            self.button2 = Button(frame, text='LED 2 OFF', command=self.convert2)
            self.button2.grid(row=4, column=0)
            self.LED2 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED2.grid(row=4, column=1)

            self.button3 = Button(frame, text='LED 3 OFF', command=self.convert3)
            self.button3.grid(row=5, column=0)
            self.LED3 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED3.grid(row=5, column=1)

            self.button4 = Button(frame, text='LED 4 OFF', command=self.convert4)
            self.button4.grid(row=6, column=0)
            self.LED4 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED4.grid(row=6, column=1)

            self.button5 = Button(frame, text='LED 5 OFF', command=self.convert5)
            self.button5.grid(row=7, column=0)
            self.LED5 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED5.grid(row=7, column=1)

            self.button6 = Button(frame, text='LED 6 OFF', command=self.convert6)
            self.button6.grid(row=8, column=0)
            self.LED6 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED6.grid(row=8, column=1)

            self.button7 = Button(frame, text='LED 7 OFF', command=self.convert7)
            self.button7.grid(row=9, column=0)
            self.LED7 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED7.grid(row=9, column=1)

            self.buttonnewwindow = Button(frame, text='Knight Rider TEST', command=self.new_window)
            self.buttonnewwindow.grid(row=10, column=0)

            self.button8 = Button(frame, text='Exit', command=quit)
            self.button8.grid(row=11, column=0)

    def convert0(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 0 ON')
            self.button0.config(text='LED 0 ON')
            self.LED0.config(image = logo)
            self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=2)
            pfio.digital_write(0,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 0 OFF')
            self.button0.config(text='LED 0 OFF')
            self.LED0.config(image = logo2)
            self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=1)
            pfio.digital_write(0,0) #turn off

    def convert1(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 1 ON')
            self.button1.config(text='LED 1 ON')
            self.LED1.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(1,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 1 OFF')
            self.button1.config(text='LED 1 OFF')
            self.LED1.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(1,0) #turn off

    def convert2(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 2 ON')
            self.button2.config(text='LED 2 ON')
            self.LED2.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(2,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 2 OFF')
            self.button2.config(text='LED 2 OFF')
            self.LED2.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(2,0) #turn off

    def convert3(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 3 ON')
            self.button3.config(text='LED 3 ON')
            self.LED3.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(3,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 3 OFF')
            self.button2.config(text='LED 3 OFF')
            self.LED3.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(3,0) #turn off

    def convert4(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 4 ON')
            self.button4.config(text='LED 4 ON')
            self.LED4.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(4,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 4 OFF')
            self.button4.config(text='LED 4 OFF')
            self.LED4.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(4,0) #turn off

    def convert5(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 5 ON')
            self.button5.config(text='LED 5 ON')
            self.LED5.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(5,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 5 OFF')
            self.button5.config(text='LED 5 OFF')
            self.LED5.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(5,0) #turn off

    def convert6(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 6 ON')
            self.button6.config(text='LED 6 ON')
            self.LED6.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(6,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 6 OFF')
            self.button6.config(text='LED  OFF')
            self.LED6.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(6,0) #turn off

    def convert7(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 7 ON')
            self.button7.config(text='LED 7 ON')
            self.LED7.config(image = logo)
            pfio.digital_write(7,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 7 OFF')
            self.button7.config(text='LED  OFF')
            self.LED7.config(image = logo2)
            pfio.digital_write(7,0) #turn off

    def new_window(self):
        print('New Window')

        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = App2(self.newWindow)
        self.newWindow.grab_set()   # I added this line to stop opening multiple new windows

class App2:

    def __init__(self, master):
            self.signal = False    #added to stop thread
            print('self.signal', self.signal)

            self.master=master    # I added this line to make the exit button work
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=0, column=1)

            self.button0 = Button(frame, text='Knight Rider OFF', command=self.convert0)
            self.button0.grid(row=2, column=0)
            self.LED0 = Label(frame, image=logo2)
            self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=1)

            self.button9 = Button(frame, text='Exit', command=self.close_window)
            self.button9.grid(row=3, column=0)


    def convert0(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]

        if tog[0]:
            print('Knight Rider ON')
            self.button0.config(text='Knight Rider ON')
            t=threading.Thread(target=self.LED)
            t.start()
            self.signal = True    #added to stop thread
            print('self.signal', self.signal)
            print('tog[0]', tog[0])
            self.LED0.config(image = logo)
        else:
            print('Knight Rider OFF')
            self.button0.config(text='Knight Rider OFF')
            self.signal = False   #added to stop thread
            print('self.signal', self.signal)
            print('tog[0]', tog[0])
            self.LED0.config(image = logo2)


    def LED(self):
            while self.signal:   #added to stop thread

                a=0

                while self.signal:   #added to stop thread
                        pfio.digital_write(a,1) #turn on
                        sleep(0.05)
                        pfio.digital_write(a,0) #turn off
                        sleep(0.05)
                        a=a+1

                        if a==7:
                                break

                while self.signal:   #added to stop thread

                        pfio.digital_write(a,1) #turn on
                        sleep(0.05)
                        pfio.digital_write(a,0) #turn off
                        sleep(0.05)
                        a=a-1

                        if a==0:
                                break

    def close_window(self):
            print('Knight Rider OFF')
            print('self.signal', self.signal)
            self.button0.config(text='Knight Rider OFF')
            self.LED0.config(image = logo2)
            self.signal = False   #added to stop thread
            print('self.signal', self.signal)


            sleep(1)
            print('Close Child window')
            self.master.destroy()   # I added this line to make the exit button work

root = Tk()
logo2 = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Off LED.gif")
logo = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Red LED.gif")

root.wm_title('LED on & off program')
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could try to present a distilled version of your example. Most people are not able to run this code because of the dependencies. Try to create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your code is more complex than it needs to be. For example, you don't need threads for what you are trying to do. Tkinter widgets have a method named `after` which can be used for animation or calling funtions on a schedule.

Comment: @Aivar yes I'll make a distilled version and post it up. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley yes I guess it is more complex than it needs to be, but I'm learning and their seems to be many ways to do things and threading was the one I tried in this instance but I will look into the 'after' thing you mentioned. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the LED to be set to off when the new window is opened, then you can use a class attribute and set it how ever you want.  This example, with all of the extra cruft removed does that.  If this is not what you want then post back.

```
class App:

    def __init__(self):
        master=Tk()
        self.master=master
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.toggle=0
        self.newWindow=False
        self.button0 = Button(frame, text='LED 0 OFF', command=self.convert0)
        self.button0.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.LED0 = Label(frame, text="Label")
        self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.buttonnewwindow = Button(frame, text='New Window',
                                     command=self.new_window)
        self.buttonnewwindow.grid(row=10, column=0)

        self.button8 = Button(frame, text='Exit', command=quit)
        self.button8.grid(row=11, column=0)

        master.mainloop()

    def convert0(self):
        self.toggle=not self.toggle
        if self.toggle:
            print('LED 0 ON')
            self.button0.config(text='LED 0 ON')
            ##self.LED0.config(image = logo)
            ##self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=2)
            ##pfio.digital_write(0,1) #turn on
        else:
            print('LED 0 OFF')
            self.button0.config(text='LED 0 OFF')
            ##self.LED0.config(image = logo2)
            ##self.LED0.grid(row=2, column=1)
            ##pfio.digital_write(0,0) #turn off


    def new_window(self):
        print('New Window')

        if not self.newWindow:
            self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
            Button(self.newWindow, text="Close Window", command=self.newWindow.destroy).grid()
            ##self.app = App2(self.newWindow)
            ##self.newWindow.grab_set()   # I added this line to stop opening multiple new windows
            self.toggle=1
            self.convert0()
            self.newWindow=False
App()
```

Comment: i took the advice of one of the commentors and created a distilled version of my problem and posted that up.  Thanks for the example.  Being a newbie it takes me a bit of time to break it down and understand how it works.